# MS Access VBA is creating multiple report emails and parameters are not storing reference from form

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have am working on a report to pull employees with end dates between two unbound text fields on a form. The report is grouped on Supervisor. My goal is to save each report grouping as unique PDFs with the PDF name as the [Supervisor] - John Smith.PDF, Jill Smith.pdf etc. This report is attached to an email, which is opened and waiting for adjustment prior to sending.

Currently, this works except for a couple issues that I am trying to solve:

1. I get a Parameter popup asking for StartDate and EndDate (my parameters set to the form text fields) before each report opening. I have to manually enter this date for each parameter before each report, it is not populating from the form.
2. I get multiple emails opened for each supervisor. Some have blank reports. It seems like I am getting one for each record of each report, with the parameter popup for each.
3. After I hit the button, I input the dates into the parameter popups. My reports opens, saves, closes, and an email is generated correctly. Instead of moving to the next report/email automatically, I have to manually enter the date into the parameter popups again.

My Form has two fields Text0 and Text2 and a Button that will print a report based on the query below using VBA.

**Query SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Active and Expired Badges].Supervisor_Clean, [Active and Expired Badges].FIRSTNAME, [Active and Expired Badges].LASTNAME, [Active and Expired Badges].[Premera ID], [Active and Expired Badges].Company, [Active and Expired Badges].Title, [Active and Expired Badges].[End Date], [FIRSTNAME] & " " & [LASTNAME] AS Name
FROM [Active and Expired Badges]
WHERE ((([Active and Expired Badges].Title) Like "*" & "outsource" & "*" Or ([Active and Expired Badges].Title) Like "*" & "Contingent" & "*") AND (([Active and Expired Badges].[End Date]) Between [StartDate:] And [StopDate:]));
```

**Button VBA:**

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()

'split report into PDFs named after supervisor and open a separate email with each report attached

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim StartDate As DAO.Parameter
    Dim StopDate As DAO.Parameter

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("30-Day query")
    mypath = "C:\Users\cw52450\Desktop\Test Exports\"
    qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value = [Forms]![EndDate]![Text0]
    qry.Parameters("StopDate").Value = [Forms]![EndDate]![Text2]

    Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)  
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then

'populate rs

    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

'start report generation loop

    Do While Not rs.EOF       

        temp = rs("Supervisor_Clean")
        MyFileName = rs("Supervisor_Clean") & Format(Date, ", mmm yyyy") & ".PDF"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "End Date Report", acViewReport, , "[Supervisor_Clean]='" & temp & "'"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "End Date Report"
        DoEvents

'start mail section

    open Outlook, attach zip folder or file, send e-mail
    Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MailOutLook
        .SendUsingAccount = appOutLook.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        '.To = ""
        ''.cc = ""
        ''.bcc = ""
        .Subject = "Non-Employees with Expiring Building Access"
       .HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Hello,</p><p>The attached report... </p></body></html>"
       .Attachments.Add (mypath & MyFileName)
        '.DeleteAfterSubmit = True 'This would let Outlook send the note without storing it in your sent bin
        .Display
    End With
'end mail section

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
    MsgBox "Report generation complete."
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qry = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup for parameters could be because of incorrect syntax here:

```
qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value = [Forms]![EndDate]![Text0]
qry.Parameters("StopDate").Value = [Forms]![EndDate]![Text2]
```

Try to change it to:

```
qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value = Me.Text0
qry.Parameters("StopDate").Value = Me.Text2
```

Comment: Errors out with "Error 3061 - Too Few Parameters. Expected 4." on  
```Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)```

Comment: If this is a date variable try to add # sign around it: qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value = "#" & Me.Text0 & "#"
You can also test it like:
qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value ="#1/1/2020#"

Comment: Both ways get a Data Type Conversion error. My form does have the Text0 and Text2  fields set to short date format and my query End Date is short date format as well. Report is the same.

Comment: I am sorry, I think it should be like this: qry.parameters("StopDate") = #3/7/17#